# Spark 2.0.0 - No FileSystem for scheme: null error in IntelliJ SBT project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

After a recent upgrade to Spark 2.0 from Spark 1.6.1 one of my IntelliJ Idea Scala programs seem to be unable to run and exits with the message "No FileSystem for scheme: null error". I have googled the error but seem to get hdfs related errors and they seem unrelated to what I see.

I did make code changes related to changes in Spark 2.0. The change was to rather use a SparkSession rather than SparkContext and SparkSQL.

Find the code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object PropertyInvestmentCalcs {
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark PropertyInvestmentCalcs")
  .master("spark://ODROIDXU41:7077")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "\\\\SERVER\\Users\\USER\\MYDrive\\Programming\\IntelliJ\\PropertyInvestmentCalcs\\spark-warehouse")
//val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession(spark)

// Get number of data records in the table
val nrRecordsDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test")
  .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .option("dbtable", "(SELECT COUNT(*) AS nrRecords FROM test.propertydb) AS nrRecords_tmp")
  .option("user", "user")
  .option("password", "password").load()
nrRecordsDF.show()
nrRecordsDF.printSchema()
}
}
```

Contents of my build.sbt file:
    import sbt._

```
name := "PropertyInvestmentCalcs"

version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" //% "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0" //% "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.0.0" //% "provided"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.39"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  organization := "TJVR",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
)

lazy val app = (project in file("app")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
// your settings here
  )

artifact in (Compile, assembly) := {
  val art = (artifact in (Compile, assembly)).value
  art.copy(`classifier` = Some("assembly"))
}

addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assembly), assembly)
```

Contents of my plugins.sbt file:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The Spark SQL Warehouse directory setting is kinda Hadoop related if it uses a `HiveContext`. I think the problem arises at `\\\\SERVER\\\`. With the leading slashes.

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, thanks for your comment. If I don't specify that server URL then I get a message saying: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:C:/Users/USER/Drive/Programming/IntelliJ/PropertyInvestmentCalcs/spark-warehouse

It seems that anything loaded from the database gets stored in HDFS storage. There is however issues with HDFS from my point of view. Please correct me if I am wrong. 

Unfortunately the issue persists.

Comment: I've never seen spark read from NFS / SMB storage. What do you have against HDFS or moving the file to the local filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (thanks to @cricket_007):

Remove first two trailing slashes before Server. This is not intuitive from a Windows user point of view but it is how it works.